# Delete the contents of log file periodically

Tags: c#

I wrote a scheduler application and appended the details of exceptions and other stuffs to a log file in the remote machine. What would be the best way to delete the contents periodically in the log file?

Comment: What logging framework are you using? [Log4Net supports it](http://geekswithblogs.net/rgupta/archive/2009/03/03/tips-on-using-log4net-rollingfileappender.aspx)

Comment: You can use **Timer Controls** or **Threads** to do a functionality after a *Time Interval*!

Answer (score 2):

Why roll your own? I would use a tool like [log4net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/) that already has these out of the box capabilities. It can write exceptions to a rolling log file and set the max number of files to write to. i.e. config:

```
<maxSizeRollBackups value="numberOfDays" />
```

In addition, to save disk space, could write the files to the cloud whenever file rolls such as aws s3: fork or use https://github.com/stemarie/log4net.aws